# How to fix loop Promise pending (async/await) in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm stuck with a loop generated when I used async function, and I need the object inside in the Promise to use it in Child component, this is the issue:

ParentComponent:

```
class ParentComponent extends Component {
  state={
   array:[]
  }

  async getData() {
        const {data} = await getAxiosFunction();
        let content = [...data['content']]; // object structure

        this.setState({
            array: content,
        });
    }

 render(){
   const {array} = this.state;
   
   console.log(this.getData()); // loop Promise {<pending>}

  return(
    <div>
       <button onClick={e=>{e.preventDefault(); this.getData();}}>get data</button>
       {array>0 &&<ChildComponent data={array} />}
    </div>
   )
 }

}
export default ParentComponent;
```

ChildComponent:

```
const ChildComponent =({data})=>{
  
 return(
   <div>
      ... // I need to use the object inside data
   </div>
 )
}

export default ChildComponent;
```

I hope that some one can let me some advice to apply it, thanks!

Comment: `getData` is called on every render.

Comment: You should be using `componentDidMount()` and calling `console.log(this.getData());)` in that. (https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html)

Comment: This makes little sense to me: `let content = [...data['content']];`. Wouldn't it be better like `const {content} = data;` ?

Comment: And this is not an object, it looks like an array...

Comment: This also does not makes sense: `array>0 && ...` . It should be `array.length > 0 ? ... : null`.

Comment: As an optimization, declaring the `onClick` lambda function directly in render would be better declared as a class method (with arrow function to bind it to the instance) and used directly: `onClick={ this.onGetData }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you use `console.log(getData())` in the render part.

The flow like :

**reder => run `getData` => setState => render => run `getData` => setState .....** (infinite loop)

I fix you sample code and make it work, like :

( Or you can check here [image: Edit TextField selectionStart] )

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";

const ChildComponent = ({ data }) => {
  return <div>{data}</div>;
};

class ParentComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.getData = this.getData.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      array: []
    };
  }

  async getData() {
    // const {data} = await getAxiosFunction();
    // let content = [...data['content']]; // object structure
    let content = ["Hi, you click button"];
    this.setState({
      array: content
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { array } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <button
          onClick={(e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            this.getData();
          }}
        >
          get data
        </button>
        {array.length > 0 && <ChildComponent data={array} />}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ParentComponent;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call you getData method inside componentDidMount() which will get executed only once after your component is mounted successfully.

```
class ParentComponent extends Component {
  state={
   array:[]
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
    this.getData();
  }

  async getData() {
        const {data} = await getAxiosFunction();
        let content = [...data['content']]; // object structure

        this.setState({
            array: content,
        });
    }

 render(){
   const {array} = this.state;
   

  return(
    <div>
       <button onClick={e=>{e.preventDefault(); this.getData();}}>get data</button>
       {array>0 &&<ChildComponent data={array} />}
    </div>
   )
 }

}
export default ParentComponent;
```

And if you want to get the data on button click then you can do

```
class ParentComponent extends Component {
  state={
   array:[]
  }

  async getData() {
        const {data} = await getAxiosFunction();
        let content = [...data['content']]; // object structure

        this.setState({
            array: content,
        });
    }

 render(){
   const {array} = this.state;
   

  return(
    <div>
       <button onClick={() => this.getData()}>get data</button>
       {array>0 &&<ChildComponent data={array} />}
    </div>
   )
 }

}
export default ParentComponent;
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the sandbox with fix https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-mtd8v3

Do not call the `getData` in render method (console.log), which will cause infinite loop.

```
import React from "react";

class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    array: []
  };

  async getData() {
    const { films: data } = await fetch(
      "https://swapi.dev/api/planets/1/"
    ).then(res => res.json());
    let content = [...data]; // object structure

    console.log("--", content);

    this.setState({
      array: content
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { array } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <button
          onClick={e => {
            e.preventDefault();
            this.getData();
          }}
        >
          get data
        </button>
        {array.length > 0 && <div> {JSON.stringify(array)} </div>}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <ParentComponent />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

State mutation methods inside `render()` will cause infinite re-rendering.

```js
render() {
  const { array } = this.state;

  // uncomment me for infinity
  //console.log(this.getData());

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={(e) => this.handleOnClick(e)}>getData</button>
      <Child data={array} />
    </>
  );
}
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/66504205-0ecg1)